# How can I do highlight in record color React js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In `View All Profile` when an employee has exhausted their leave allocation for Annual, Casual, Medical  highlight in record color.
condition we can take  annual leave per year 14days(if 14days finished then that 14 number should be highlight.also Casual leave and Medical leave per year 7days(if 7days finished then that 7 number should be highlight.

[image: here is my project UI]

table code:

```
 <Table  pagination={{ pageSize: 10 }} columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
```

state coding:

```
 state = {
      filterDropdownVisible: false,
      data: [],
      fullData: [],
      searchText: '',
      filtered: false,
    };
```

getdata methode code:

```
 getdata() {
      this.props.actions.getData().then(() => {
        if (!this.props.viewAllProfile.getDataPending) {

          this.setState(
            {
              data: this.props.viewAllProfile.ProfData.profiles,
              fullData: this.props.viewAllProfile.ProfData.profiles,
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

table code:

```
 render() {
      const columns = [{
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        render: (text, record) => (
          <Link to={`/user-profile/${record.id}`}>{text}</Link>
        ),
        filterDropdown: (
          <div className="custom-filter-dropdown">
            {/* <Input
              ref={ele => this.searchInput = ele}
              placeholder="Search name"
              value={this.state.searchText}
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              onPressEnter={this.onSearch}
            />
            <Button type="primary" onClick={this.onSearch}>Search</Button> */}
            <Search
              placeholder="By name..."
              value={this.state.searchText}
              ref={ele => this.searchInput = ele}
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              onPressEnter={this.onSearch}
              onSearch={this.onSearch}
              enterButton
              style={{ boxShadow: '1px 1px 3px gray', borderRadius: 5 }}
            />
          </div>
        ),
        filterIcon: <Icon type="search" style={{ color: this.state.filtered ? '#108ee9' : '#aaa' }} />,
        filterDropdownVisible: this.state.filterDropdownVisible,
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
          this.setState({
            filterDropdownVisible: visible,
          }, () => this.searchInput && this.searchInput.focus());
        },
      }, {
        title: 'Annual',
        dataIndex: 'anual',
        key: 'anual',
      }, {
        title: 'Casual',
        dataIndex: 'casual',
        key: 'casual',
      }, {
        title: 'Medical',
        dataIndex: 'medical',
        key: 'medical',
      }, {
        title: 'Special',
        dataIndex: 'special',
        key: 'special',
      }, {
        title: 'No pay',
        dataIndex: 'no_pay',
        key: 'no_pay',

      }
      ];
```

Comment: Annual +  Casual + Medical = 14 days or individual 14 days and also can you show the code for <Table/> component. ?

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey sir i updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `render` function to highlight specific values.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Casual',
    dataIndex: 'casual',
    key: 'casual',
    render: val => val === 14 ? <span className="highligt">val</span> : val
  }
]
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? there was a mistake in the code .. try now

Comment: you must somewhere define that class  in your CSS `.highligt { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare constants for each type of leave and while rendering the data in the table in `<td></td>` you can compare the leaves count and update add the `highlight_red` class using conditional JSX.

```
//In table.jsx

const TOTAL_ANNUAL = 14
const CASUAL_LEAVE = 7
const MEDICAL_LEAVE = 7

<td className={i.annual_count == TOTAL_ANNUAL ? "highlight_red" : ""}>{i.annual_count}</td>
<td className={i.casual_count == CASUAL_LEAVE ? "highlight_red" : ""}>{i.casual_count}</td>
<td className={i.medical_count == MEDICAL_LEAVE ? "highlight_red" : ""}>{i.medical_count}</td>


//In your style.css

.highlight_red{
 color : red;
 }
```

Comment: what's the issue which you are facing now ?

Comment: how to write code for if max num 7 then highlight that 7 num

Comment: which plugin are you using for rendering table ?

Comment: from ant design sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174180/discussion-between-gnanaseelan-and-subhanshu-pandey).